# comparing elements in an array and fetching new ones

Tags: java, arrays, compare, processing

I realize this has been asked before and I had a look at it but, for me, it only works to a point. After some struggle, I thought I'd ask.
I have an array of floats in an object's constructor.

That goes like this:

```
count = 3;
angles = new float[count];
```

The array length is really small though I'd like implement a modular and reusable approach.

I loop through the array assigning floats:

```
for (int i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {
        angles[i] = radians(random(360));
}
```

Then, with a new loop, I check if the singular elements have less than 30 degrees in between them, and if so, assign a new random value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {
        for (int k = i+1; k < angles.length; k++){
            if(angles[i] != angles[k]){
                if(abs(angles[i] - angles[k]) <= radians(30)){
                    angles[i] = radians(random(360));
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This works nice and well but it doesn't guarantee that the new random number will keep the 30 degrees limit with the remaining elements. This, I assume, has to do with the length of the 'for' loop.

What would be the best way to overcome this and guarantee that newly fetched number will always conform to the 30 degree rule?

Comment: [Think about how you would do this with a piece of paper and a pencil.](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just checking once with an if statement, you could change it to a while statement, so that it attempts to find a new random number until the new one works.

```
while (abs(angles[i] - angles[k]) <= radians(30)){
    angles[i] = radians(random(360));
}
```

However, if there are no numbers that follow your 30 degree rule, your program will get stuck in this loop, so you might want to check that there is a possible solution before entering the loop.

Edit: the above solution will ensure that the number follows the 30 degree rule with only one number in your array. Add a boolean to determine if the condition has been met, and loop until the boolean is true.

```
for (int i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {
    boolean meetsCondition = false;
    while (!meetsCondition) {
        for (int k = 0; k < angles.length; k++){
            if(i != k){
                if(abs(angles[i] - angles[k]) <= radians(30)){
                    angles[i] = radians(random(360));
                    meetsCondition = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        meetsCondition = true; //if the for loop completes, it has met the condition.
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems very logical and elegant so I gave it a shot. It seems to be working fine in most of the cases but, I gotta say, not always. And I'm not messing with the values anywhere else in the program. I'm a bit puzzled.

Comment: @katotopark I fixed the bug in the code (I had just copied your code and added the while loop). The problem was starting the second for loop at `k = i+1` instead of `k = 0`, and the new value didn't recheck itself against the old values.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use recursion earlier on:

```
for (int i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {
    angles[i] = findSuitable( i==0 ? 0 : angles[i-1] )
}


... 

float findSuitable(float limit){
       float sample = radians(random(360));
       if(Math.abs(sample-limit) > 30)
           return sample;
       else
           return findSuitable(limit);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you can try to change the the codes of random to this:

Random d = new Random();
int a = d.nextInt(360);